# VMware remote virtual serial port concentrator

Tags: cisco, vmware-vsphere, serial

I'm setting up a Cisco virtual wireless controller using the guide provided here: http://www.labminutes.com/wlc0001_vwlc_7_3_vmware_installation

The narrator talks about making sure your VMware is licensed for "Remote Virtual Serial Port Concentrator". That feature is not listed for my VMware but I do see options for it on my virtual machines. Is there some place else I need to enable this in VMWare? What license(s) does this feature come with?

I'm using vSphere with Operations Management 5.1 Standard.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone's curious, you need an Enterprise or Enterprise + license.